# traefik not working when a service is in multiple overlay networks

Tags: docker-swarm, traefik

```yaml
version: '3.2'

services:
  traefik:
    image: "traefik:latest"
    command:
      - --entrypoints.web.address=:80
      - --entrypoints.websecure.address=:443
      - --providers.docker=true
      - --providers.docker.swarmMode=true
      - --providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false
      - --providers.docker.network=public
      - --api
      - --log.level=ERROR
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    networks:
      - public
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"

  agent:
    image: portainer/agent
    environment:
      # REQUIRED: Should be equal to the service name prefixed by "tasks." when
      # deployed inside an overlay network
      AGENT_CLUSTER_ADDR: tasks.agent
      # AGENT_PORT: 9001
      # LOG_LEVEL: debug
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /var/lib/docker/volumes:/var/lib/docker/volumes
    networks:
      - agent_network
    deploy:
      mode: global
      placement:
        constraints: [node.platform.os == linux]

  portainer:
    image: portainer/portainer-ce:2.0.0
    command: -H tcp://tasks.agent:9001 --tlsskipverify
    volumes:
      - data:/data
    networks:
      - public
      - agent_network
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]
      labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.portainer.rule=Host(`portainer.yourdomain.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.portainer.entrypoints=web"
      - "traefik.http.services.portainer.loadbalancer.server.port=9000"
      - "traefik.http.routers.portainer.service=portainer"
      # Edge
      - "traefik.http.routers.edge.rule=Host(`edge.yourdomain.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.edge.entrypoints=web"
      - "traefik.http.services.edge.loadbalancer.server.port=8000"
      - "traefik.http.routers.edge.service=edge"

networks:
  public:
    external: true
  agent_network:
    external: true

volumes:
```

We can see that "portainer" is in both public and agent_network overlay networks. And it has two IP addresses, 10.0.38.7 and 10.0.39.7.

traefik is only in public network, it has IP address 10.0.38.6.

The problem is, from traefik web UI, it refers "portainer" as 10.0.39.7 instead of 10.0.38.7. So that it fails to work.
Any solution to this?

Comment: Same issue for multiple networks in docker.